# Issue when using decode in SQL query where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been mulling over a problem for the last few hours with a query which executes a decode statement as part of my WHERE CLAUSE.

The best Example I can come up with here is as follows:

```
--This variable is normally populated by a query.
--Debugger confirms this is set to 'US' with no leading or tailing characters
Str_MyVar varchar2(10) := 'US';

-- Query 1 returns 16 rows (incorrect)
Select *
From myTable, table2
Where myTable.value = decode(Str_MyVar, 'US', table2.value, 0)

-- Query 2 returns 1 rows (correct)
Select *
From myTable, table2
Where myTable.value = decode('US', 'US', table2.value, 0)
```

Now then, if I change the query which populates the Str_MyVar variable to instead convert the value 'US' to a 1 and all other values to a 0 and store it in a numeric variable things begin to work.

```
--This variable is normally populated by a query.
--Debugger confirms this is set to 1 with no leading or tailing characters
nbr_Myvar number := 1;

-- Query 1 returns 1 rows (correct)
Select *
From myTable, table2
Where myTable.value = decode(nbr_MyVar, 1, table2.value, 0);
```

This second example using a numeric data type for the variable in the decode works properly.  The question is Why?  Sure I've coded around the issue but I'd like to understand if this is an oracle bug or just a quirk of the DECODE function.  Database is oracle 10.2.0.3

Comment: From the top of my head, can you just try giving 0 in DECODE in single quotes in query 1 and try once

Comment: `table.value` is not declared in the query. Did you mean `myTable.value`?

Comment: table.value is meant to represent some other table I an referencing, I'll clarify, thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this; can you create a complete example with table definitions etc. so it can be replicated? Though it doesn't really sense to me...